# How to make conditional panels with dynamically created tabs in Shiny R?

Tags: r, user-interface, dynamic, tabs, shiny

Okay, so I'm able to dynamically create tabs that are assigned values to an id, so I can access them. I'm able to create conditional panels in the UI (where they're normally found) if I want to put something on a specific dynamically created tab, but I'm having trouble finding a way to dynamically create conditional panels on my tabs.

Here's my code, I'll explain it below:

UI:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(navbarPage("TiGr",

                   tabPanel("File Input Page",
                            fluidPage("Input")),

                   tabPanel("Summary Statistics and Plots",
                            fluidPage("Statistics")),

                   tabPanel("Time Clusters",
                            fluidPage("cluster"),
                            actionButton("subClust", label = "Create Subcluster"),
                            uiOutput("tabs"),
                            uiOutput("condo"),
                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.level==1",
                                             numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 9,
                                                          min = 1, max = 9)
                            ), 
                            conditionalPanel(condition="input.level==2",
                                             uiOutput("int1"))

                   )
))
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$tabs=renderUI({

    Tabs<-as.list(rep(0,input$subClust+1))
    for (i in 0:length(Tabs)){
      Tabs[i]=lapply(paste("Layer",i,sep=" "),tabPanel,value=i)
    }
    do.call(tabsetPanel,c(Tabs,id="level"))
  })


  output$condo=renderUI({
    for (i in 1:input$subClust+1){
      conditionalPanel(condition=paste("input.level==",i,sep=""),
                       numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 9,
                                    min = 1, max = 9))
    }
  })



  outVar<-reactive({
    vars <-input$clusters
    return(strtoi(vars))
  })
  output$int1=renderUI({
    numericInput('clusters1', 'Cluster count', outVar(),
                 min = 1, max = outVar())
  })

  condVar<-reactive({
    vars<-input$subClust
    return(strtoi(vars))
  })

}
)
```

So in the UI, the tab of importance is the time clusters tab. I have a button that I can click that will create new tab pages. I then have the tab output and an attempt at an automated conditional panel output (does nothing).

I have 2 conditional panels defined explicitly, (I want to be able to put these all in uiOutput("condo"), but right now they're just used to highlight the difference in outcomes between explicitly creating conditional panels and trying to make them dynamically.

The server page has a method to output the tabs, a method that tries to make conditional panels (does nothing), and some other methods that relate to dynamic inputs. (input 2 resets to input 1, whenever input 1 changes).

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong with the conditional pages method in the server? (this is R's output of the explicit form)

```
> conditionalPanel(condition="input.level==1",
+                  numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 9,
+                               min = 1, max = 9))
<div data-display-if="input.level==1">
  <label for="clusters">Cluster count</label>
  <input id="clusters" type="number" value="9" min="1" max="9"/>
</div>
```

And this is R's output of my attempt

```
> conditionalPanel(condition=paste("input.level==",1,sep=""),
+                  numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 9,
+                               min = 1, max = 9))
<div data-display-if="input.level==1">
  <label for="clusters">Cluster count</label>
  <input id="clusters" type="number" value="9" min="1" max="9"/>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove the for-loop in my server file, I'm able to get the extra slider displayed on the most recent page, but I can't seem to keep it. So if I click the button 3 times -> 3 sliders on 3 pages, and if I click the button 4 times -> 2 slider on first 2 pages, and 1 slider on last page. 

Does anyone know how to dynamically add multiple components to the same renderUI method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to find a solution, by looking at a relevant problem, the issues around creating tabs dynamically. I just changed tabs into conditional pages and ran a do.call with the main panel at the end to properly format my conditional pages.

What I've learned is you can't just make a for loop with a bunch of UI features and expect them to pop up (sadly, it doesn't work like that). Here's my server code that changed:

```
  output$condo=renderUI({
    ConPages<-as.list(rep(0,condVar()+1))
    for (i in 0:length(ConPages)){
      ConPages[i]=lapply(paste("input.level==",i,sep=""),conditionalPanel,numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 9, min = 1, max = 9))
    }
    do.call(mainPanel,list(ConPages))
  })
```