# R shiny Multiple slider inputs based on checkbox inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have used the below code to create checkbox from my data.I would like to create slider input for each checkbox I select from the list.For example if the checkbox has 4 variables like "sky","earth","water","fire" and if I select sky, it should dynamically open a slider input for sky and if I select water it should open up one more slider input for water. I tried conditionalPanel,but I have more than 50 variables in my checkbox,so i cannot write condition for all the 50 variables. Is there any generalized method available in shiny?

server

```
output$choosedigital=renderUI({

if(is.null(bk$variables))
   return()

checkboxGroupInput("choosemedia", "Choose digital", 
                    choices  = bk$variables,
                    selected = bk$variables)
})


  output$test <- renderUI({
  LL <- list(rep(0,length(input$choosedigital)))     
  for(i in 0:(length(input$choosedigital))) {
   LL[i] <- list(sliderInput(inputId = paste(input$choosedigital,i)
                             , label = paste(input$choosedigital,i), 
  min=0,max=25,value = 5))
  }       
  return(LL)                      
  })
```

Comment: I think you need to loop with `lapply`.  Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: bk=mydigital
   
   output$choosemedia=renderUI({
     
     if(is.null(bk$variables))
       return()
     
     checkboxGroupInput("choosemedia", "Choose digital", 
                        choices  = bk$variables,
                       selected = bk$variables)
     
   }) ;  code for slider input ;

   output$test=renderUI({
     if (is.null(input$choosemedia))
       return()
     

          switch(input$choosemedia,
            sliderInput("dynamic", "Dynamic",
                                   min = 1, max = 20, value = 10))
        
     

       })

Comment: I have updated my code using for loop.But still its not working.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You want to put your sliderInputs inside a conditionalPanel in the UI and set the condition so that when the relevant checkbox is clicked the the condition equates to TRUE.

e.g.

```
library(shiny)
myData = c("One", "Two", "Three")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  checkboxGroupInput("choosemedia", "Choose digital", 
                     choices  = myData,
                     selected = myData),
  textOutput("myText"),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choosemedia.includes('One')", 
                   sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose your value", min=0, max=100, value=50)
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choosemedia.includes('Two')",
                   sliderInput("sliderTwo", "Choose your other value", min=0, max=50, value=25)
  )
    )

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myText <- renderText({input$choosemedia})
   
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If long as you know what the content of bk$variables is you can hardcode them, otherwise you'll have to generate these on the fly.

Hope this is enough info to get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,but what i wanted is slightly different.I don't want to write conditional panel for each input,because i have more than 50 variables inside the checkbox.

Comment: Is it not possible to generate the conditionalpanels using a loop and renderUI? I will admit I haven't ventured there.

Comment: I think this might give you the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732810/how-to-make-conditional-panels-with-dynamically-created-tabs-in-shiny-r)

Comment: I tried replicating using the code given in the link   The UI as follows  conditionalPanel(condition="input.level==1",
                                                     sliderInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 9,
                                                                  min = 1, max = 9))    Server                         output$test=renderUI({
     
     Tabs<-input$choosemedia
     for (i in 1:length(Tabs)){
       Tabs[i]=lapply(paste("input.level==",i,sep=""),conditionalPanel,sliderInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 9, min = 1, max = 9))
     }
     return(Tabs)
   })